# How to design alert dialog box in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-alertdialog

What can I do to design a alert box in flutter in which we have a tick mark on the top of the box half inner side and half outer side of the dialog box. Where we have some successful message

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far ?

Comment: We are not able to see expected output image.

Comment: i am sorry i am not able to include my image in flutter ..

Comment: In my alert box i want to add tick mark on top half inner side and half outer side

Comment: You can wrap the widget with Transfrom.translate or  if it is having transform, use it when it is doesnt need to have tap event.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is probably what you want:

```dart
Stack(children: [
  Positioned(
    top: 16,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    child: YourDialogWidget(),
  ),
  Positioned(
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    child: YourCheckMarkWidget(size: 32),
  ),
]),
```

Customize as you see fit.